# How to create twilio c++ application

Tags: c++, twilio

I am new to Twilio. I want to implement call functionality in win 32 application using twilio.
The application should able to call a phone number similar to skype.
I went through the docs and tried some code related making a call. I see that callee receives call, and on picking the call, it says what I am setting in url then it hangs up.

I tried different Url created through twimlets.
I don't see a way to connect my application to that phone call. Following is my code,

```
string response;
vector<Var> vars;
Rest t (ACCOUNT_SID, ACCOUNT_TOKEN);

// make a call
vars.clear();
vars.push_back(Var("To", "+12345678900"));
vars.push_back(Var("From", "+14243327777"));
vars.push_back(Var("Url", "http://twimlets.com/echo?Twiml=%3CResponse%3E%3CSay%3EHi+there.%3C%2FSay%3E%3C%2FResponse%3E"));

response = t.request("/" + API_VERSION + "/Accounts/" + ACCOUNT_SID + "/Calls", "POST", vars);
cout << response << endl;
```

Please guide.

Thanks
R.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

So just to be clear I understand what you are asking, you want to be able to have your application make an outbound phone call and then talk to the person you called right through that app?

If that is the case unfortunately there is not really a good way to do this in a native Windows application.  We do have a VoIP solution called Twilio Client, but today we only offer SDK's for JavaScript and native iOS and Android platforms.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, want to make outbound phone call through my windows application. are you not supporting VoIP solution on windows anymore?

Comment: Please comment on twilio c++ lib (https://github.com/laurentluce/twilio-cplusplus).
What can we do using the Twilio C++ library.

Comment: This is a library that makes it easier for C++ developers to use Twilios REST API by wrapping the API in a C++ API.  So as you've seen, you can use it to have Twilio initiate an outbound phone call from Twilios servers to a telephone.  The REST API currently does not have a way for you to create an audio connection directly between your desktop app and Twilio.  Today the only platforms we support for VoIP style audio connections are JavaScript, iOS and Android via our Twilio Client SDK's: https://www.twilio.com/client